# disparity map creation opencv

Tags: image, opencv, computer-vision, disparity-mapping, correspondence

I have 2 image one is left the other is right image. I want to implement disparity mapping. There are some questions in my mind.

Firstlty dispartiy image is 1 channel gray image but the left and right images are 3 channels bgr images. If we convert these 3 channels image to gray image, do i loss information? If yes, how can i get disparity image from 3 channels img to 1 channel disparity image. I mean how can demote to 3 channels image to 1 channels image to get disparity image?

Thanks for answers..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are losing information by combining all three channels into a single channel grayscale image.

There are certainly algorithms that use 3 channels to compute a disparity map, but opencv does not contain functions that implement these algorithms.

Have you considered taking out each channel R, G and B and computing the correspondence for each seperately?  Of course, you would need to figure out a clever way to combine the results into one final disparity map, but it could be fun!

Answer (score 0):

Try first to find the corresponding pixels, then apply SAD difference on the two matrices, then find the minimum value and display it at the disparity map.